# Creating Time Series in R studio (data is on excel sheet)

Tags: r

i need some help with the solution of a problem.
The task refers  to : Walmart daily sales in three US states (CA, TX and WI) for the period 01-02-2011 to 31-12-2014 (1,430 comments).

I'm trying to come through these questions :
i)Visualize the four daily sales timelines in a common chart. Based on the diagram, list the key quality characteristics of time series that they display.

ii) Evaluate the linear correlations of time series and indicate whether they are significant or not.

iii) Calculate the average sales share of the three states on the company's total sales. Also, calculate the same average percentages for each year, month of the year and day of the week. Are there differences in them, and if so, what conclusions can be drawn?

Here is the data in Excel :https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1gF2h6jt16kYziGMXgQ_tgfe3iZ4YhZKy

For the first thing I write :

```
#from Feb 2011 to Dec 2014 as a time series object
myts <- ts(WalData, start=c(2011, 2), end=c(2014, 12), frequency=12)
myts
```

but it is ofcourse FALSE,
i need time series for CA , TX, WI and Total
and then i must combine them !

Please help i cant find how to make these timeseries for my variables !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: open the link and i give you access on excel sheet with the information of sales etc..

Comment: Can you open up the data (or a sample of it) to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: how can i give you the sheet , how can i show you the data ???

Comment: You can use the `dput()` function in R. Read the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: and now you can have the data in order to help me with the code i must write in R ??

Comment: i cant find how to give you my data my numbers of walmart sales ..@Werner

Comment: WalData
       CA    TX    WI Total       date event_type snap_CA snap_TX snap_WI
1   11047  7381  6984 25412 2011-02-01       <NA>       1       1       0
2    9925  5912  3309 19146 2011-02-02       <NA>       1       0       1
3   11322  9006  8883 29211 2011-02-03       <NA>       1       1       1
4   12251  6226  9533 28010 2011-02-04       <NA>       1       0       0       for example some of sales , but i cant load all the data of the sheet please help !

Comment: @Werner i put a photo of some data (sales) i hope anyone can help with codes !